# Spring Boot Date TimeZone settings applications not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, date, timezone

I have simple question i use this configuration in application.properties
in Spring Boot

```
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd
spring.jackson.time-zone=Europe/Zagreb
```

but it's not working

when i use this annotation on class is work correct

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd",timezone = "Europe/Zagreb")
```

Any idea what is bad?

Comment: Did you put `application.properties` in the right location?  Did you spell the file name correctly (you say `...propertis` in your post).

Comment: Sorry my mistake i put in application.properties

Comment: But this configuration not work i don't have idea why

Comment: “but it's not working” does not make an acceptable question on Stack Overflow. Rewrite to be very specific and descriptive. Voting to close as needing details.

Comment: Dates do not have a time zone.

Comment: In json i have timestamp in wrong timezone i try use this configuration

spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd
spring.jackson.time-zone=Europe/Zagreb

but nothing change

Use this i have correct date
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd",timezone = "Europe/Zagreb")

I don't now why configuration global in application.properties not work
this my problem

Comment: Yes, and her format is timestamp

Comment: “yyyy-MM-dd” makes a date-only, not a timestamp. In Java use `LocalDate`, and in standard SQL use `DATE`. A timestamp is more. A timestamp is composed of a date, a time-of-day, and a time zone or offset-from-UTC (usually an offset of zero in database work). In Java use `OffsetDateTime` for exchanging values with a database, and in standard SQL use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Comment: Ok, thank but what do you think why global config not work?

Comment: We don't know what you mean by "not work" so we can't answer. You need to provide explicit examples that demonstrate the issue.

Comment: According to the documentation Formatting JSON Dates in Spring Boot, it should set the global date format and timezone in json, but when I use it, it has no effect, the returned date has the form of a timestamp, when I use the @JsonFormat annotation for a given DTO field is ok, I'm curious why this global configuring with application.properties doesn't change anything return is timestamp, which I possibly do wrong.
Sorry for incomprehensible questions.

Comment: I don't find solution why configuration on application.properties not work,
just i use this ammotation on dtos Date fields
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd",timezone = "Europe/Zagreb")